# Selecting between two dates within a DateTime field - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

How to select records between a date to another date given a DateTime field in a table.

Comment: isn't it discussed/asked over here previously?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443555/sql-syntax-select-results-for-each-date-between-a-range-of-dates


Search rules! ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE myDate BETWEEN #date one# AND #date two#;
```

Comment: between is terribly misunderstood. casting of dattime to date happens intentionally and unintentionally. Personally I like explicit >= and <= because it does not save much typing but is so much less readable.

Comment: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE item_id=2884 AND (start_date BETWEEN '2020-09-05 23:31:45' AND '2020-09-06 00:00:00' OR
end_date BETWEEN '2020-09-05 23:31:45' AND '2020-09-06 00:00:00') )

This is my code, but it doesnt work well

Answer (score 19):

```
select * 
from blah 
where DatetimeField between '22/02/2009 09:00:00.000' and '23/05/2009 10:30:00.000'
```

Depending on the country setting for the login, the month/day may need to be swapped around.

Answer (score 0):

select * from
table name (exm.User)
where column name (exm.Date) between '2022-10-10 08:00:00' and '2022-
10-11 12:00:00'